# What does Quine's ontological method of paraphrasing achieve?

Tags: ontology, quine

W. V. O. Quine in "On What There Is?" denies the existence of universals. There are red things, like a fire truck (*f*), a tomato (*t*), a red umbrella (*u*). But the phrase *"They have* redness *in common"* is in his view just a manner of speech, in which *redness* does not refer to an actual entity (a universal). Instead it just means that the predicate *R*(*x*) = "*x* is red" can be applied to them all: *R*(*f*) ∧ *R*(*t*) ∧ *R*(*u*).

Quine managed to paraphrase the claim without some existential claim occurring. So according to his standard, his ontological theory does not commit to the existence of universals.

But as Howard Peacock notices, we also talk about things just having *something* in common (indeterminate). Two things *a* and *b* having something in common seems to mean ∃*P*: *P*(*a*) ∧ *P*(*b*) with *P* being a predicate and so "existence" again. We would have to say that just a formula like *P*(*a*)  ∧ *P*(*b*) applies to avoid the existential quantifier.

Yet if we have two things *a* and *b* for which it is true that *a* is unlike anything else, and *b* is unlike anything else, this predicate of *U*(*x*) = "*x* is unlike anything else" can be both applied to them: *U*(*a*) ∧ *U*(*b*). But it seems wrong to state that *a* and *b* have something in common.

So at least at this point, Quine's translation probably does not catch the original meaning of the phrase; we distinguish between aspects of a thing (that play a role in the concept of "being like") and just any random predicate which applies to things.

If we don't find a simple way out of that, couldn't we just say that Quine's translation of "have something in common" does not apply to any predicate but only to certain special predicates? Maybe we can't give a definition for those special predicates, but do we have to?

As we see from the discussion there are two issues:

(a) How do we handle existence claims that occur when the paraphrasing method is defined? Like above "a formula like" seems to commit to types (of formulas). But if the paraphrase method succeeds wouldn't it also be able to paraphrase the method itself?

(b) Can an "incomplete" ontological theory be judged to commit to certain entities for which existence claims are made but no fully generalized paraphrasing method is available -- or not?

It seems that the avoidance to tackle the question what "is" *means* just postpones it. It emerges later again, in a more obscure way. (a) and (b) seem just convoluted ways to ask: "What do you mean by 'is'?".

On the other way around, if our theory admits that there is a subset of predicates that work like universals, may this not be just close enough to metaphysical realism for all purposes? What does it even matter if we get around using an existence claim?

Should we not explore if the existence claim of metaphysical realism has any further content than "like" sometimes being objective, found in the nature of things, and sometimes not?

So how can *anything* of importance be gained from Quine's method, which refuses to engage with the meaning of "is"? Ignoring the meaning of "is" / "exists" and just shuffling words around until the offending word does not occur anymore -- what did Quine try to achieve with that?

Comment: Quine does not really care what "we talk about" in general, or catching "the original meaning", he explicitly derides "ordinary language" philosophy, and "meaning" is an odious term for him. Ontology is to be based on scientific talk, and that is what he cares about, folk distinctions between predicates and "aspects of things" are not it. What paraphrase does not "catch" is a good riddance. This is why the "ideal scientific language" is first order, predicates are admitted into it sparingly, and quantifying over predicates is ruled out by design. So it wears its ontology on its sleeve.

Comment: @Conifold this is only about his meta-ontological method, the "explicit standard whereby to decide what the commitments of a theory are", not who he prefers ontology to work. If he doesn't care about what we talk about, why did he even propose this standard? And to be of any interest it must somehow apply to ordinary language, or we couldn't use it on *any* non-formalized theory. He does not allow second-order logic, but then the paraphrasing may in certain cases appeal to schemas, which is another major issue, because use of schemas seems like an existential claim (i. e. of types).

Comment: Remember, this is "to decide what the commitments of a theory are" *from Quine's point of view*, it is *for him* to formulate the disagreement. Others, obviously, may not share his physicalism or "*a criterion of ontological commitment which turns on a real or imagined translation of statements into quantificational form*". So, "*it is not
with ordinary language, it is rather with one or another present
or proposed refinement of scientific language, that we are concerned...*", see his Logic and Reification of Universals. Hence a lot of "junk" gets cut out before we even get to paraphrasing.

Comment: @Conifold well,  I hope that you don't quote out of context here. If you're right, he (a) managed to hide this "unfairness" extremely well in his essay, in which he repeatedly tells us in a rather irenic tone that this is just an impartial method to find out what other ontologies commit to, and (b) it's strange that his criterion became canonical.

Comment: [Logic and the Reification of Universals](http://www.thatmarcusfamily.org/philosophy/Course_Websites/Readings/Quine%20-%20Logic%20and%20Reification%20of%20Universals.pdf) is online, the quoted passages are on p.106. But already in On What There Is he remarks "*When **I** try to formulate our difference of opinion, on the other hand, I seem to be in a predicament.*" (emphasis his). I think it became popular because good chunks of language can be expressed in predicate calculus+, and those are analytic philosophers focus on, and it does provide a partial guide to sorting out commitments.

Comment: Formalizing sayings like "have something in common" requires (the existential fragment) of second-order logic basically.

Comment: @Fizz why can't we for universals introduce an instantiation relation. ∃u: I(a, u) ∧ I(b, u). To do it with predicates creates problems...

Comment: @Conifold ok, I still find Quine's remarks rather innocent. Of course others may disagree how Quine translates their ontology into first-order logic. But he can still claim that he does it in good faith. And when talking about differences in opinion about the existence of X, "X" will appear in his sentences -- it's obvious that he doesn't want to to commit to the existence of X just to determine a difference in opinion.

Comment: It is interesting that it is now a majority view that Quine's criterion is too strict even for *scientific* language. Scientists themselves distinguish in their theories between "things represented", that they are committed to ontologically, and "representational aids", like mathematical objects, see [Azzouni, On "On What There Is"](http://www.thatmarcusfamily.org/philosophy/Course_Websites/Logic_F09/Readings/Azzouni.pdf). Ironically, I think this would please Quine himself. He always had nominalistic sympathies, and was only forced to accept existence of sets and numbers by his criterion.

Comment: @Conifold thanks, the linked paper partly expresses ideas I had in mind. Tried to go a stronger route though, not that Quine's criterion begs the question but that it's not even well-defined. Still surprising for you to say Quine would've liked it. We surely still have to bother with the concept of "is" as from the title of "On what there is?"; so the analysis of what this concept means is back on the table (as unavoidable). You can't say something interesting about "is" while maintaining that it's odious to engage with its "meaning".

Comment: The pleasing part is that a lot of "junk" (by Quine's lights) gets weeded out by paraphrase, and now,  on top of that, even being a quantified variable *after* paraphrase does not force a commitment. So the ontology can be thinned down further. One can then go full nominalist/empiricist, as Azzouni suggests, and ultimately dissolve "is" into epistemic stories and pragmatics.

Comment: @Conifold ok, I find this very strange. Granted it might've been Quine's personal meta-ontology. but it's not just a somewhat question-begging and incomplete stance like his original criterion anymore. It's just saying that no discussion can take place at all. It's like Marx's false consciousness. Plato: "There are platonic forms" Quine: "Well, you don't really think so. But if those forms work for you, you're allowed to talk like that". Sorry but "is" has a meaning at least insofar that there is 100% philosophical consensus that at least something is. Which goes beyond epistemol./pragmatics.

Comment: Well, one can not really bar others from employing "is" as they see fit. But one is free to translate what they are saying, or the part one finds cogent/salient, into one's preferred vocabulary. And that is the consensus on "something is", like Rorschach blot each fills it with their own. The discussion can still take place, substantively when there are vocabulary overlaps, but globally only on pragmatic output. Quine originally preserved at least some shadow of ontological "is" in the "amalgam of science with applied mathematics", but, as it turned out, even that can be dispensed with.

Comment: No epistemic or ontic POV is perfect. Quine's ontology is bottom-up style and thus more fit to educate or communicate with most laypeople without all those necessary Platonic Forms cultivated in the correctly trained mind already from sensual experiences as a second nature...